# Typo3 widget paginate very Slow and not Cached

Tags: php, caching, pagination, typo3-6.2.x

I want to have a paginate on my Typo3 Extension. So I use the widget:paginate from Typo3. I have 4.000 Datasets. But this widget is very slow!!! And it don't be cached! For 10 Items per Page, it need 15 Seconds, because it load all Datasets not only the 10 (Lazy Loading is active). And also it generate for all Pages the Links (incl. realUrl), 10 Items per Page by 4.000 Datasets = 400 Pages. I set the option maximumNumberOfLinks: 10. So It should be generate only 10 Links. But It generate all 400 everytimes.

I found a solution to cache the widget:paginate here: http://xopn.de/blog/two-surprising-typo3-performance-tips-for-extension-developers

With this litte change, my Page rendert with empty Cache in 2 Sec. With cache 0,5 Sec. But now the Pagination don't work, it will display every time the Datasets from the first Page.

I think this Problem have more people like me, but I don't find good informations on Google.

Do you have some ideas or good informations about this Problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted, the question seems legitimate to me. Can you post your code?

Comment: I use the same code like the link. And all normal widget:paginate code. I have see on my mysql log, that the widget don't be cached, and do too much queries. So I ask Google to get a solution because I think this is not a Problem on my System, it is a Problem in the Widget. I don't belief to be the first that see this.